# What happens if you equip the Crown of the Sunken King at 99 strength?

Tags: dark-souls-2, dark-souls-2-sotfs

[Crown of the Sunken King](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Crown+of+the+Sunken+King+Helm) gives you a +1 STR bonus. What happens when you wear it with 99 base STR? I mean will your STR be 100? Will your damage bonuses increase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on information provided by users [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/693331-dark-souls-ii/69802545), it doesn't look like your stats will be boosted over 99, which is the cap.

> My answer to that....most likely not. Other items that raise stats dont break the 99 limit
>
> It doesn't increase it over 99 I think because using a ring of prayer doesn't increase faith over 99

That is, based on the behavior of other stat-boosting equipment, it's assumed that the Crown of the Sunken King behaves the same way.

Comment: Yes. I've just checked it.